# How to show items in Zebble ItemPicker?

Tags: xamarin-zebble, zebble

I set the control.datasource of formfield to a object and then
fill it in code behind, but when I tap on it on run time it just show
class name of the object insted of value which I set.

I think I have already followed the documentation here: 
[Zebble ItemPicker-Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAvTW.png)

my code is :

```
 mypage.zbl

<FormField z-of="ItemPicker" Id="Type" LabelText="Type" 
  Control.AllowNull="true"
  Control.DataSource="@(Database.GetList&lt;ContactType&gt;())" />

myentity

public partial class Contact : GuidEntity
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

[here is a screen shot of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAvTW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the data source of an ItemPicker to some **list of objects**, the **ToString()** of that object will be displayed for each item.

The easiest fix for your problem is to add a ToString() method to your source class:

```
public partial class Contact : GuidEntity
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public override string ToString() => this.Name;
}
```